# Actionscript 3.0 and MVC

Tags: actionscript-3, model-view-controller, frameworks, design-patterns

How do you implement MVC in actionscript 3.0? Do you build your own classic (based on GoF book) simple architecture or use some of modern frameworks? I learn on "classic solution" and couldn't understand is it better to use some mvc framework? Which one is good for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use my own setup that implements MVC practices/architecture, but is not a framework. In my mind, MVC is a way of organizing the code (and functionality). Available MVC frameworks features to simplify and automate interaction.
For many of my projects, the added  functionality of an MVC framework is not needed and just ends up imposing some restrictions. If these features are important or you're working with a team, the mvc framework has many benefits. But for personal projects, I find the simplicity of my own setup does the job.

Comment: Thank you so much, now i see that the difference is in project size and team cooperation. Frameworks is just more powerful tool and "general" solution, when you need basic functional and work alone it is better to make your own solution.

Answer (score 2):

There are several AS3 MVC implementations, the most popular of them are Robotlegs, PureVMC, Swiz and Parsly (there are also Cairngorm and Flex only MATE but I don't know have they still supported). They all managed to be the basis for your application and it's a matter of taste which of them to use. If I should make a choice of one on them it'll be the Robotlegs, but in real work we have own lite weight MVC implementation, something average between Robotlegs and Cairngorm for pure AS3 projects.

Comment: +1 for RobotLegs.  I would advise against rolling your own MVC framework at this point - there are plenty of good open source frameworks you could help make better.

Comment: Thank you for such a good recommendation, i just was thinking about Robotlegs as my first MVC experience and i found it really great. I would like to accept this answer too but it's impossible, so you need to know that it was really helpful too.